# Migrating from Facebook version v1.0 to v2.2

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

For migrating the code to 2.2 version, there are many places where the code is directly calling https://graph.facebook.com/{id}/picture. Do i have to modify all these places to https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/{id}/picture to make the calls version compliant?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can modify all your calls to call the current version of the API (which is v2.3) or you can specify the version number. If you don't specify the version number, calls will default to the current version available, right now v1.0 and after April 30th, v2.0. This changelog doc lists the current available api version and the changes in it : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply!